# PCL - Targetting .NET 4.5.2 and ASPNetCore 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, portable-class-library

I have a PCL where I target .NET 4.5.2 and ASP.NET Core 1.0, but whenever I reference this PCL from my DotNetCore AspNetCore 1.0 app.

### Fix:

Turned out to be an issue with ReSharper, after installing 2017.1 EAP 3, (going from 2016.3) referencing a shared .NET Standard 1.2 project is working perfectly fine!

### Question

## UPDATE

Managed to get it to compile by changing the Target Framework of my PCL to `.NET Framework 4.5` rather than `.NET Framework 4.6` (don't ask me why it worked, but would definitely like to find out why).

It is now compiling successfully but my IDE is not resolving references correctly

[image]

### Original Error

I get a compilation error, saying that it is is not compatible.

1. Is it possible to have a single PCL targeting .NET 4.5.2 and DotNetCore (not using .NET Standard which is not out yet)
2. How do you do it?
3. Can I do this in latest VS 2017 RC? (or should I install VS2015?)

## Error Message

[image]

## PCL Targets

[image]

## PCL Referenced in AspNetCore

[image]

## AspNetCore 1.0 Project Setup

[image]

## .NET Standard Implementations

Reason why I cannot use .NET Standard is highlighted in the following:

[image]

Comment: Do you have both a csproj and xproj file?

Comment: What the hell are you talking about? NETStandard was released with .NET Core (which was released at the same time as ASP.NET Core, June or July 2016)

Comment: What's the exact error message you receive?

Comment: @Tseng ok, go and tell me what .NET core version has full access to .NET 4.5.2 APIs (or at least DataTable). I guess what I meant to say is that a "usable" non core .NET standard is released

Comment: @CraigSelbert no, all of them are .csproj

Comment: @HenkMollema See first screenshot

Comment: @TânNguyễn thanks, i'm currently constrained to .NET 4.5.2 highest, as I need to put out a library that supports that version, and speaks to my AspNetCore API. Hence why I want to use a PCL for shared code between them (models etc). By the way you know in File Explorer, you can click on url, type in "cmd", and hit enter. It will do the same as Shift Right Click + Open command window here

Comment: @MichalCiechan: You are mixing terms here. NETStandard is a Api **SUBSET** which guarantees that certain api runs portable. And of course 4.5.2 is there and supported, even on the screen you posted yourself. .NET 4.5.1/4.5.1 is supported by `netstandard1.2` or higher. Of course you can't use APIs which are not supported on all targeting platforms. The NETStandard, same as PCL only makes the lowest API available which are supported by all targets. In PCL it did depend on the PCL profile, in Netstandard on the netstandard version which represents certain api set (rather than target platforms)

Comment: Or in other words: When you create an `netstandard1.2` library you can consume it in .NET 4.5.2 (and higher), Win8 & Win8.1, in UWP but not in silverlight. `netstandard1.3` on will not be able to be consumed by Win8 & Win8.1, but you will have more apis available for use, but less platforms. So the higher the netstandard verison, the more apis are available and the less platforms can be targeted (netstandard2.0 being an exception as it will have lower requirement than 1.6, but new .NET Core API only available in netstandard1.6 will be available in netstandard2.1

Comment: @Tseng I know, but I would have to target .NET Standard 2.0 which isn't implemented by Core 1.0. Where as according to apisof.net it is referenced  System.Data.Common in .Net Core 1.0 but never made the cut into any of the Standards until 2.0!

Comment: @MichalCiechan: Then you can't use "NETCoreApp 1.0" as targeting app and you have to target ".NET Framework 4.5" in your ASP.NET Core project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshots you can see that your ASP.NET Core application is targeting `NETCoreApp1.0`.

Under **NO CIRCUMSTANCES** you can use .NET 4.5 libraries in .NET Core. You have to either a library/package which targets `netstandard1.x` (1.2 in your case, if minimum API is .NET 4.5.1 or 4.5.2) or which targets a compatible PCL (i.e. `portable-net45+win8` or similar).

If you **need/have to** use a .NET 4.5/4.6 library which doesn't target `netstandard1.x`, then you must change `NETCoreApp1.0` from your ASP.NET Core application (not the PCL) Project settings to `.NET Framework 4.5`.

> I know, but I would have to target .NET Standard 2.0 which isn't implemented by Core 1.0. Where as according to apisof.net it is referenced System.Data.Common in .Net Core 1.0 but never made the cut into any of the Standards until 2.0!

But then you can't just run it on Linux/MacOS on .NET Core. This limits you to use your ASP.NET Core application on Windows or Mono on Linux/MacOS.

#### Update

With .NETStandard you can also target `net451` and `netstandard1.x` at the same time and use preprocessing directives to conditionally compile code into one of the assemblies.

For that you need to create a new "Class Library (.NET Standard)" project and edit project.json (if you are using VS2015) or the csproj (VS2017) to add the targets.

project.json

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.2": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Some.NetCore.Only.Dependency": "1.2.3"
      }
    },
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Some.Net451.Only.Dependency": "1.2.3"
      }
    }
  },
```

or csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard1.2;net451</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451' ">
  <!-- Framework references -->
  <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
  <!-- Framework references -->
  <PackageReference Include="Some.Net451.Only.Dependency" Version="1.2.3" />
  <!-- Projects within solution references -->
  <ProjectReference Include="My.Domain.Core" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.2' ">
  <PackageReference Include="Some.NetCore.Only.Dependency" Version="1.2.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When compiled/packaged it will create two binaries, one for `netstandard1.2` and one for `net451`.

In code, use your well known `#if` directives (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tutorials/libraries.md#how-to-multitarget) for a list of netstandard directives)

```
#if NETSTANDARD1_2
using Some.NetStandardOnly.Namespace;
#endif
using System;

#if NET451
public DataTable GetDataTable() 
{
    ...
}
#endif
```

Comment: I want a PcL where I can do #if net else pragma statements. Hence trekking my PcL to target .Net 4.5 and asp.net core 1.0

Comment: You can do that with `netstandard1.2` too, you just target both: `netstandard1.2` and `net451` and use `#if NET451` to compile code only into the :NET 4.5 assembly but not into the `netstandard1.2`

Comment: I've created a new library targeting just .NET Standard 1.2. I created an empty class, and tried to reference it from my .NETCore 1.0 App but no luck. Getting the following error: `Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ClassFromPcl' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: lol, looks like it was an error generated by JetBrains ReSharper. Installed latest 2017.1 EAP3 and it is working fine! God i hate being on the bleeding edge!